# Jade template with scripts doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, pug

I am facing an issue with Jade templates. I have uploaded a sample Jade template to Parse Cloud code, and it works properly. It is as simple as the following:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Sample App
  body
    h1 Hey
    p= message
```

When I upload the template, which I have coded, it returns an Internal Server Error. There are some scripts I have added, and generally, if I add a script to the sample described above, the uploaded file fails to work.

Here is how I'm adding the scripts:

```
script(type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/circles.js")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you adding scripts to your template? What are the errors? The code snippet you provide isn't enough.

Comment: Just edited my post. I'm getting an Internal Server Error. Thanks.

Comment: You should have more showing in your server logs, an internal server error is just what you get in the browser. Are the scripts where jade thinks they are? Is the tag indented correctly?

Comment: Make sure the Jade template compiles locally. And don't the attributes on that script tag need to be separated by either commas or a newline?